# How we can perform live encoding of videos to mp4 and stream it in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, video-streaming

I'm using flow player for streaming videos to my browser.The videos are uploaded by the users and they may upload different formats. What will be solution to stream the videos as mp4 , what ever be the format they upload. I'm currently using ffmpeg commands.

The problem is after encoding the video is getting down scaled.Also if the user upload large video file the encoding itself takes more time.

I need to stream the videos as soon as its uploaded to the server, what ever may be the format(like in youtube).

Answer (score 1):

I'd look into [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) as it allows yo to transcode just about every video format on the planet.

However; I'm not sure of it's real-time capabilities or it's abilities to stream it's output. Might be a good place to start though.

Comment: It doesn't have to be real time - just transcode when the videos are uploaded and save the result, then stream that to the browser.

Comment: That will take more time if the user upload a large media file

Comment: ffmpeg commands are degrading the quality of my videos.Can any one please suggest a ffmpeg command that will not degrade the quality.I only need to convert to H.264 format

Comment: The encoding ffmpeg uses is fully configurable on the command line. You're going to have to find the settings that work for you. Check the docs http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html

Comment: That set of commands i had seen ,I'm for the best parameters for a default encoding.i need to convert the format only, no upscale and downscale of quality

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do this by automating expression encoder on the server even though it is mainly used for smooth streaming format but expression encoder isn't opensource or free :(

Comment: Expression encoder 3 is free.i also tried that.but need to upgrade to SL.